# Asymptotic Behavior of Ratio of Random Variables

Tags: probability, limits

Let $X_n \ge 0$ and $Y_n > 0$ be sequences of random variables. Suppose that for a positive sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}$, $P(Y_n < a_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $X_n/a_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

My question is: can we say that $X_n/Y_n \rightarrow 0$ in some  (probabilistic) sense? If there are further conditions under which this is true, what are they?

I know that if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converged to constants $a$, $b$ in probability, we would have $X_n/Y_n \rightarrow a/b$ in probability.

Some things I have tried:

1. Split the ratio in two cases with indicators $1(Y_n \ge a_n)$ and $1(Y_n \le a_n)$.
2. Try to combine Markov with Cauchy-Schwarz to provide an upper bound.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A book that treats lots of problems similar to this is Sefling's _Limit Theorems of Mathematical Statistics_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Rescale by $a_n$ to get $P(Z_n<1)\to 0$, $H_n\overset{p}\to 0$ to immediately yield $X_n/Y_n=H_n/Z_n\overset{p}\to 0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I know what you mean (well, I did $P(H_n/Z_n > \epsilon) = P(H_n/Z_n > \epsilon \cap Z_n > 1) + P(H_n/Z_n > \epsilon \cap Z_n \le 1) \le P(H_n > \epsilon) + P(Z_n \le 1) \rightarrow 0$ to convince myself that the last step was true, but that wasn't much work) . Would you like to write it as an answer? I don't know if you care about the bounty, but you earned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{X_n}{a_n}=o_p(1)$, $\frac {a_n}{Y_n}=O_p(1)$, hence their product $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}$ is $o_p(1)$.

Comment: 1/n is o(1) and thus also O(1), but (1/n)/(1/n) is not o(1). ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky *Product*, not *ratio*.

Comment: Er, yeah. ​ (sneaks off) ​ ​ ​ ​