# type and rate of convergence of ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics, self-learning, rate-of-convergence

Say we have two sequences of scalar random variables $X_n\geq0$ and $\widehat{\theta}_n>0$, where

- $X_n = o_p$(1) and we know $X_n = \mathcal{O}_p(n^{-1})$, i.e., $X_n$ converges (in probability) to zero at rate $n^{-1}$.
- $\widehat{\theta}_n$ is a $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator of $\theta>0$ : $\widehat\theta_n - \theta = \mathcal{O}_p(n^{-1/2})$, i.e., $\widehat\theta_n$ converges (in probability) to $\theta$ at rate $n^{-1/2}$.

Q: Is it true for the ratio $R_n := X_n / \widehat\theta_n$ that,

1. $R_n = o_p(1)$, i.e, $R_n$ converges to zero (in probability)?
2. $R_n = \mathcal{O}_p(n^{-1})$, i.e., the rate is $n^{-1}$?

I think that 1. follows along the argument in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639676/297213) answer,

$$\frac{X_n}{n^{-1}} = \mathcal{O}_p(1) \, ; \, \frac{n^{-1}}{\widehat\theta_n} = o_p(1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad R_n = \frac{X_n}{n^{-1}}\cdot\frac{n^{-1}} {\widehat\theta_n} = \mathcal{O}_p(1)\cdot o_p(1) = o_p(1).$$

But 2. is just a guess from looking at computer simulation results and I don't know how to obtain the rate.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write
$$
\frac{X_n}{\widehat{\theta}_n} 
= \frac{X_n}{\theta} \cdot \frac{\theta}{\widehat{\theta}_n} 
= \frac{X_n}{\theta} + \frac{X_n}{\theta}\left( \frac{\theta}{\widehat{\theta}_n}  - 1 \right) .
$$
Note that $\frac{X_n}{\theta} = O_P(n^{-1}$) and $\frac{\theta}{\widehat{\theta}_n}  - 1 = o_P(1)$. (Since $\widehat{\theta}_n - \theta = o_P(1)$, a bit of limit manipulation using the fact that $\theta$ is a real number can be used to show this.)

Therefore, using $O_P(n^{-1}) o_P(1) = O_P(n^{-1})$, the above expression satisfies
$$
\frac{X_n}{\widehat{\theta}_n} = O_P(n^{-1}) + O_P(n^{-1}) \, o_P(1) = O_P(n^{-1}) .
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on why $\frac{\widehat{\theta}_n}{\theta} = o_p(1)$? This can't be since $\frac{\widehat{\theta}_n}{\theta}\rightarrow 1$. I also don't see how $\frac{\widehat{\theta}_n}{\theta} = o_p(1)$ follows from the statement in parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, I think that's a bit of a typo. I've added in an edit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I still think that there's something odd. Shouldn't it be $\frac{X_n}{\widehat{\theta}_n} = \frac{X_n}{\theta} \cdot \frac{\theta}{\widehat{\theta}_n} = \frac{X_n}{\theta} + \frac{X_n}{\theta}\left( \frac{\theta}{\widehat{\theta}_n} - 1 \right)?$

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The argument is essentially the same.